# visual basic function discounts 1 and 2

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on a code for my class and I'm having trouble with the function part.

I currently have this. I need a function that accepts the subtotal and calculates the discount using Subtotal > 200 then a discount of 1%
Subtotal > 100 then a discount of .5%

I am struggling with functions and need help if somebody could point me in the right direction please and thank you.

```
Public Class Form1
    Const constHandWashPrice As Decimal = 10D
    Const constInteriorShampooPrice As Decimal = 30D
    Const constCarWaxPrice As Decimal = 25D
    Const constEngineShampooPrice As Decimal = 15D
    Const constInteriorVacuumPrice As Decimal = 16D
    Const constOilChangePrice As Decimal = 34.95D
    Const constRustProofingPrice As Decimal = 89.99D
    Const constTireRotationPrice As Decimal = 15D
    Const constAlignmentPrice As Decimal = 63.88D
    Const constFrontBrakesPrice As Decimal = 75.66D
    Const constRearBrakesPrice As Decimal = 78.9D
    Dim discount As Decimal
    Dim total As Decimal
    Dim subtotal As Decimal
    Dim customername As Integer
    Dim address As Integer

Private Sub cbservices_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbservices.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim index As Integer
    Dim price As Decimal
    Dim msg As String

    index = cbservices.SelectedIndex

    If index = 0 Then
        price = constHandWashPrice
        total += constHandWashPrice
        subtotal += constHandWashPrice
    End If
    If index = 1 Then
        price = constInteriorShampooPrice
        total += constInteriorShampooPrice
        subtotal += constInteriorShampooPrice
    End If
    If index = 2 Then
        price = constCarWaxPrice
        total += constCarWaxPrice
        subtotal += constCarWaxPrice
    End If
    If index = 3 Then
        price = constEngineShampooPrice
        total += constEngineShampooPrice
        subtotal += constEngineShampooPrice
    End If
    If index = 4 Then
        price = constInteriorVacuumPrice
        total += constInteriorVacuumPrice
        subtotal += constInteriorVacuumPrice
    End If
    If index = 5 Then
        price = constOilChangePrice
        total += constOilChangePrice
        subtotal += constOilChangePrice
    End If
    If index = 6 Then
        price = constRustProofingPrice
        total += constRustProofingPrice
        subtotal += constRustProofingPrice
    End If
    If index = 7 Then
        price = constTireRotationPrice
        total += constTireRotationPrice
        subtotal += constTireRotationPrice
    End If
    If index = 8 Then
        price = constAlignmentPrice
        total += constAlignmentPrice
        subtotal += constAlignmentPrice
    End If
    If index = 9 Then
        price = constFrontBrakesPrice
        total += constFrontBrakesPrice
        subtotal += constFrontBrakesPrice
    End If
    If index = 10 Then
        price = constRearBrakesPrice
        total += constRearBrakesPrice
        subtotal += constRearBrakesPrice
    End If

    msg = cbservices.Items.Item(index) & vbTab & FormatCurrency(price)

    lbss.Items.Add(msg)



    lblsubtotal.Text = FormatCurrency(subtotal)


End Sub

Private Sub ClearToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ClearToolStripMenuItem.Click
    lbss.Items.Clear()
    lbprint.Items.Clear()
    lblsubtotal.Text = ""
    txtad.Text = ""
    txtcn.Text = ""
    subtotal = 0
End Sub

Private Sub ExitToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ExitToolStripMenuItem.Click
    If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to exit?", MsgBoxStyle.OkCancel) = MsgBoxResult.Ok Then
        Application.Exit()

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub PrintToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PrintToolStripMenuItem.Click

    Dim index As Integer



    lbprint.Items.Add("Sam's customer Care")
    lbprint.Items.Add(Environment.NewLine)
    lbprint.Items.Add("Bill to:" & txtcn.Text.ToString & vbTab & txtad.Text.ToString)

    lbprint.Items.Add(Environment.NewLine)

    Do While index < lbss.Items.Count
        lbprint.Items.Add(lbss.Items(index))
        index += 1
    Loop
    lbprint.Items.Add("--------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    lbprint.Items.Add("Subtotal: " & FormatCurrency(subtotal))
    lbprint.Items.Add("Discount: " & FormatCurrency(discount))




End Sub
```

Comment: There arent any functions there

Comment: I'm not sure to implemtn the function ive tried different things but it did not work

Comment: This is not a tutorial site. [Function Statement (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sect4ck6.aspx) do some research then post what you have tried and ask a specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a function that **given a total makes a discount**? Like this?

```
Private Function GetDiscountedTotal(subtotal As Decimal) As Decimal
   Return If(subtotal > 100, If(subtotal > 200, subtotal - (subtotal * 0.1D), subtotal - (subtotal * 0.5D)), subtotal)
End Function
```

**Example of usage**

```
subtotal = GetDiscountedTotal(subtotal)
```

Comment: I need a function that will produce a seperate discount price from the subtotal either 1% or .5_

Comment: @ryandonald thats what that function does